# Muti-level array from multiple JSON files

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have to pull a bunch of json files and create links from information in those files and go into the files recursively.

```
{
  "_v" : "12.2",
  "categories" : [ {
    "id" : "boys-hats-and-beanies",
    "name" : "Hats & Beanies"
    }
  ]
}
```

so from that I need to build another url to go into and get the file contents of

http://xxx.xxx/?id=boys-hats-and=beanies.json

and inside that file I might have to do it again. As I have it right now it puts the information I need in to many array's and I would like it to keep the hierarchy.

```
$allLinks['root'] = array();
$allLinks['firstLevel'] = array();
$allLinks['secondLevel'] = array();
$allLinks['thirdLevel'] = array();

    function getContent($info){
        $content = file_get_contents($info);
        return json_decode($content, true);
    }

    $new = getContent('https://xxx.xxx/?id=root');


    foreach ($new['categories'] as $name => $value) {
            array_push($allLinks['root'], 'https://xxx.xxx/?id='.$value['id']);
    }

    foreach ($allLinks['root'] as $name => $value) {
        $new = getContent($value);
        foreach ($new['categories'] as $name => $value) {
            array_push($allLinks['firstLevel'], 'https://xxx.xxx/?id='.$value['id']);
        }
    }

    foreach ($allLinks['firstLevel'] as $name => $value) {
        $new = getContent($value);
        foreach ($new['categories'] as $name => $value) {
            array_push($allLinks['secondLevel'], 'https://xxx.xxx/?id='.$value['id']);
        }
    }

    foreach ($allLinks['secondLevel'] as $name => $value) {
        $new = getContent($value);
        foreach ($new['categories'] as $name => $value) {
            array_push($allLinks['thirdLevel'], 'https://xxx.xxx/?id='.$value['id']);
        }
    }


    print_r($allLinks);
```

So you can kind of see what I'm trying to get at. Please any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your trying to store the urls in an array, this should return all the urls in a multidimensional array with 0 being the first level.

```
function getContent($info){
    $content = file_get_contents($info);
    return json_decode($content, true);
}

function getContentUrlById($id, $ext = '.json')
{
   return 'https://xxx.xxx/?id=' . $id . $ext;
}

function getContentRecursive($id = 'root', $level = 0)
{
    $result = array();
    $url = getContentUrlById($id);
    $content = getContent($url);
    $result[$level][] =  $url;
    foreach($content['categories'] as $cat){
      $result = array_merge_recursive($result, getContentRecursive($cat['id'], $level + 1));
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: That give me this

`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://xxx.xxx?id=root
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://xxx.xxx/?id=mens
        )`
And so on..